# Error Code:0x80040256 Action failed for assembly 'CaseCreatePlugin': Assembly must be registered in isolation

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have a managed solution which contains a plug-in which has registered by Plug-in Registration tool. I exported that solution and while trying to import it in server I'm getting the following Error.

> Error Code:0x80040256
>
> Error Message: Action failed for assembly 'CasePlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e98dc0610752b7a': Assembly must be registered in isolation.

Can you help me what is the problem here..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the plugin was not registered in Sandbox-Mode. Therefore you need to have Deployment-Administrator privileges to import this solution.

Change the "Isolation Mode" of the assembly to "Sandbox" and export the solution again.

I strongly recommend to register all plugins in sandbox mode (isolation). Following restrictions apply for the plugin in the sandbox

> In this isolated environment, also known as a sandbox, a plug-in can make use of the full power of the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK to access the organization Web service. Access to the file system, system event log, certain network protocols, registry, and more is prevented in the sandbox. However, sandbox plug-ins do have access to external endpoints like the Windows Azurecloud.

See [Plug-in Isolation, Trusts, and Statistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx)

Only use the non-isolated mode, when you have a real need for it. For example if you need access to the file system.

> In summary, the sandbox is the recommended execution environment for plug-ins as it is more secure, supports run-time monitoring and statistics reporting, and is supported on all Microsoft Dynamics CRM deployments.

Comment: But for sandbox its showing "reduced functionality" in registration process. Its not for online instance. Is it OK..?